# Can I execute a function in RegExp declaration inline on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to get the following regexp variable:

```
const r = /(fruits)\/(apple|mango|dragon-fruit)/i;
```

To achieve it I want to execute one operation, like this:

```
const fruitsArray = ['apple', 'mango', 'dragon fruit'];
const r = /(fruits)\/(fruitsArray.join('|').replace(/\s+/g, '-'))/i;
```

Or at least like this - place a string variable:

```
const fruitsArray = ['apple', 'mango', 'dragon fruit']
let str = fruitsArray.join('|').replace(/\s+/g, '-'); // "apple|mango|dragon-fruit"
const r = /(fruits)\/(str)/i;
```

For the second case I know I can use `RegExp` constructor:

```
const r = new RegExp('fruits/' + str, 'i');
```

But I'd like to perform the operation right in the `/foo/i` regexp declaration version.

Is it possible in JS? Either to execute a function inline in regexp, or place a string variable in regexp.

Comment: what `let str =. ... ` mean ? That's ES6 ?

Comment: ya, you may execute it in-line. Did you try that?

Comment: if you need to execute function inline you could use syntax `RegExp((function(){return '123'})())`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, sure I did. I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags(…)`

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko, Yes, the variable declaration uses `let`, which is indeed `ES6`. The goal of that line is to create one string from array of strings. A variable. And then use that string variable in regexp declaration `/fruits\/(my-str-variable)/`

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko, Nope, it generates a regexp "as is" `/(fruits)\/(RegExp((function(){return '123'})()))$/`. It doesn't execute the code to make `/(fruits)\/(123)$/`

Comment: Why not to build regexp in that way `RegExp('/(fruits)\/' + RegExp((function(){return '123'})()) + '$/')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace all the spaces in the array elements by hyphen `-`. Use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the array elements by the pipe `|` (OR condition in the RegEx) as glue. String concatenation operator `+` is used to concat the brackets `(` and `)` (Grouping & capturing characters in the RegEx).

**To create regex from string dynamically, you've to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor syntax.**

```
new RegExp('fruits\/' + '(' + fruitsArray.map(str => str.replace(/\s+/g, '-')).join('|') + ')', 'i');
```

**Breakup:**

1. Replace all the spaces inside the array elements by the hyphen `-`

   ```
   fruitsArray.map(str => str.replace(/\s+/g, '-'))
   ```
2. Join the array by using the pipe `|` as glue

   ```
   .join('|')
   ```
3. Concat grouping characters `(` and `)`

   ```
   '(' + resultingString + ')'
   ```
4. To create RegEx from string dynamically, use `RegExp` constructor

   ```
   new RegExp('fruits\/' + string, 'i')
   ```

**Demo:**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    const fruitsArray = ['apple', 'mango', 'dragon fruit'];
    const regex = new RegExp('fruits\/' + '(' + fruitsArray.map(str => str.replace(/\s+/g, '-')).join('|') + ')', 'i');

    document.body.innerHTML = regex;
}());
```

**Note:** The forward slash `/` need to escape by preceding it with a backslash in the RegEx as RegEx uses forward slash as delimiters.